# What can I do so that when the screen-size is small, there will be a dropdown instead of the whole navbar? (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is all of my code for the navbar

---

**Midterm Project**

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link"><h2 class="nav-font2">Welcome Page</h2></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="about.html" class="nav-link"><h2 class="nav-font2">About</h2></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="characters.html" class="nav-link"><h2 class="nav-font2">Characters</h2></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="story.html" class="nav-link"><h2 class="nav-font2">Story</h2></a></li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Comment: Take a look at the [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.